# write(socket, buff, length) makes crash

Tags: c, sockets

I have a program that sends data to a mobile phone with android. Let's iamgine

//EDIT

```
while(enviado < length) {
    printf("SEND\n");
    r = write(con, buff_enviar+enviado, length-enviado);
    printf(" OK\n");
    if (r > 0) enviado += r;
    else if (r == 0) { printf(" * >> Socket cerrado [datos] (%d)\n",r); return r; }
    else if (r == -1) { printf(" * >> Error [datos] (%d)\n",r); return r; }
}
```

When I'm out of this while, I change `buff_enviar` values. When I cancel the transmission in my phone, by doing a successful socket.close(), the `write` makes my program end for no reason. So the output of my program is:

`SEND
OK
SEND
OK
SEND`

I guess it's `write` fault because it does not printf OK. ERRNO value is 61 (No data available)

I hope someone has encountered this problem before and solved it.

EDIT: Sometimes when I cancel, r = -1 so I can handle the error, but most of the time it just terminates the program. It's like randomly chosen. I'm confused :(

Kind regards,
Raúl

Comment: are you writing to the socket that is being closed? that's what it sounds like you're saying.

Comment: remember check the return value from write() @user1927490, to check how many bytes were written succesfully.

Comment: yeah, it looks like it should be r = write ...

Comment: sorry, it is. It's just i've been doing tests and forgot to add it again when writing here.

Comment: Changed and still not working. As I said, I think the problem is the write(), because it doesn't printf OK. SEND and OK are in two separate printf because I wanted to know when the program was terminating. Debugging stuff

Comment: I see. I don't think printf will crash your program, though. It's probably not printing because of write()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are writing to a closed socket, which by default generates a "broken pipe" signal (`SIGPIPE`). To be able to reliably recover from `write()`, you need to ignore `EPIPE` by calling:

```
signal (SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

somewhere in your program, for example in `main()`.

Answer (score 7):

Though the chosen answer was to ignore signal process wide, there are other alternatives:

Using `send` function with `MSG_NOSIGNAL`:

```
send(con, buff_enviar+enviado, length-enviado, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

Disabling `SIGPIPE` on socket level (not available on all kernels):

```
int flag = 1;
setsockopt(con, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, &flag, sizeof(flag));
```

Disabling `SIGPIPE` for caller thread:

```
sigset_t set;
sigemptyset (&set);
sigaddset (&set, SIGPIPE);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
```

And, finally, disabling signal process-wide (not recommended for libraries):

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also in my case there was many crash of the program without core dump

signal (SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

this line at the begin of the program have solved the problem!